# Google Wallet user initiated cancellation failing without calling postback

Tags: android-pay

I've gotten a subscription product working fine with Google's Wallet for Digital Goods, but I can't make user's cancelling their orders work correctly.

If I cancel for them via the merchant center, it works just fine (I get the postback with the orderId as expected). If the user tries to cancel (and this is the same in the sandbox and in production), they see the "Are you sure you want to cancel" dialog, and when they say "yes" it immediately fails. There is simply no delay there.

From everything I've looked at I'm not getting a postback at all in this case (and I'm handling the postback fine when we cancel from the merchant center). I've looked through the logs on our web server, as well as instrumented the postback handler, and it seems to be failing before it ever gets to my code.

Comment: Do you have any code or logs to add to your post that might help?

Comment: I don't get anything in the logs -- selecting 'cancel' in the Google Wallet Web interface just says cancelling the subscription failed with no explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem. Seems like there is something wrong at Google. These errors appear in the console.

```
GET https://224.32.32.221/90187  gr_full.js:26
GET https://224.32.32.221/90188  gr_full.js:26
POST https://wallet.google.com/manage/r903944a86542ecd9d4195e49cd5a8668/rpc/subscription 500 (Internal Server Error) com.google.checkout.buyercenter.client.buyercenter-0.js:4267
```